# First line of tag excerpts not always shown on Tags page

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt

While browsing through the tags on Chess Stack Exchange, I found something remarkable on [page 5](https://chess.stackexchange.com/tags?page=5&tab=popular):

[image]

That's not the complete excerpt for that [tag](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opening-traps), which reads

> An opening variation where the opponent is tempted to make a bad move.

The first line is simply not shown. This is not a CSS/design issue, the first line simply isn't included in the HTML.

The same thing happens a few pages later:

[image]

Comment: Seems it's happens if description starts with `(This tag) is/are`. Part before `is/are` is omitted.

Comment: It makes sense that such a feature is responsible for this behaviour, but then it's cutting off things too aggressively.